# JSONP request issue with Sencha Touch 2.1.1

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, jsonp, sencha-touch-2.1

According to Sencha Touch 2.1 documentation, you make a json request with the following method Ext.data.JsonP.request(). When I use it I get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' of undefined". I get the same error whith Ext.util.JSONP.request().

How to make a jsonp request with Sencha Touch 2.1.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have not imported required classes. To work with `Ext.data.JsonP.request`, you need to add a require like `requires:['Ext.data.proxy.JsonP']` in corresponding class. I simply prefer to add require inside app.js itself.