# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue with mobile web app

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am working on mobile web app using sencha touch 2.1. Currently I am making a login system. Do to this I am sending ajax request to remote server from my local machine with username and password in it. But I am keep getting this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://something.com/login.php?_dc=1362983327250. Origin http://dev.vclouds.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

In above error `http://dev.vclouds.com` is my `localhost`. I set it up in my apache config this way.

Here is my code for ajax request

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://something.com/beta/webservice/login.php',
        method: 'post',
        params: {
            user_name: username,
            user_password: password
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var loginResponse = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            console.log(loginResponse);
            if(loginResponse.success === "true") {
                me.sessionToken = loginResponse.sessionToken;
                me.signInSuccess();
            } else {
                me.signInFailure(loginResponse.message);
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            me.sessionToken = null;
            me.signInFailure('Login failed');
        },
        callback: function (opts, success, response) {
            console.log('callback');
            console.log(opts);
            console.log(success);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

I also tried JsonP as follow

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({  //<-- line 35
        url: 'http://something.com/beta/webservice/login.php',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        //method: 'post',
        params: {
            user_name: username,
            user_password: password
        },
        callback: function (opts, success, response) {
            console.log('callback');
            console.log(opts);
            console.log(success);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

But I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' of undefined             Login.js:35
```

Comment: That link does not answer my question.

Comment: That link *does* answer this question.

Comment: Does it say for sencha touch apps too?

Comment: Using sencha touch *might* give you some additional options, it won't prevent any of the standard options from working. It doesn't need to say "sencha touch" in the same way that a highway doesn't need to list every model of car that is able to drive along it.

Comment: @quentin will it might not solve your problem the post in question does tell you way you have the problem and also way you potentially can't solve it. What you are trying to do requires trust between the servers (the remote and yours) and if you can't establish that then you are correct in believing that it will not help you because it's specifically meant to block XSS when traust can't be established

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [JsonP](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP) instead of Ajax. Ajax can be used only if you are on the same domain ie the request being made and requested resource should be on same domain. In this case, you've different domains so you need to user `JsonP` requests.

They way you use JsonP is,

```
   Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        url: 'http://something.com/beta/webservice/login.php',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        params: {
            user_name: username,
            user_password: password
        },
        callback:function(result,response){
              console.log(response);
        }
   });
```

An important point to consider here is, with `JsonP` data will be sent via `GET` method only. You can't use `POST` method. Server also need to return the `callback` being sent in request in order to proceed execution with `callback` function. You can find a little info over my ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14868680/1211980) .

Also for CORS ie `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing` related info refer my another ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779047/1211980)

**EDIT** You need to add required class . like `requires:['Ext.data.proxy.JsonP']` in your file. Refere [undefined error with JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14662957/1211980)

Comment: Using JSON-P is Ajax … and there are quite a few alternatives to it.

Comment: Please see my update. I already used JsonP but it gives me another error.

Comment: I would like know to alternatives how to make CORS if we don't have control over server config.

Comment: sorry could you elaborate you comment?

Comment: @x4ph4r You need to add correct `require` for this. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14662957/1211980